# 3D Rotation of a point cloud around an arbitrary axis

Tags: 3d, rotation, point-clouds

I am trying to figure out 3d rotation of point cloud around an arbitrary axis. 
I am really close to understand whole math behind it but not yet.

Steps are defined below according to https://sites.google.com/site/glennmurray/Home/rotation-matrices-and-formulas/rotation-about-an-arbitrary-axis-in-3-dimensions

 (1) Translate space so that the rotation axis passes through the origin.

(2) Rotate space about the z axis so that the rotation axis lies in the xz plane.

(3) Rotate space about the y axis so that the rotation axis lies along the z axis.

(4) Perform the desired rotation by θ about the z axis.

(5) Apply the inverse of step (3).

(6) Apply the inverse of step (2).

(7) Apply the inverse of step (1).

Should I apply these steps for all points in the cloud by one by or should I find a center for the points in the cloud and then apply? 
Or would it both give same result?

If I draw a vector to centroid from the arbitrary  axis and apply the steps above to find tranformation matrix, then multiply all points with that matrix, will I make it right?

The other way I thought would be drawing vectors for each points and apply the steps for each individual points. This will result each point will have different transformation matrix I guess.

I am trying to integrate them in PCL C++.

Comment: What does drawing the points have to do with transforming them? Just create a single transformation matrix for the entire cloud. Also, see [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19297/how-can-i-rotate-about-an-arbitrary-point-in-3d-instead-of-the-origin) for how to rotate around an arbitrary center.

Comment: But transformation matrix being generated includes the components of the vector. How can I generate one transformation matrix to apply them all? 
Or I am confusing about the 3d rotation matrix?

Comment: Components of what vector? A transformation matrix can be implemented with many types of transformations, including rotations, scaling and translations, *without* prior knowledge of any points / vectors it will be applied to.

Comment: ok, i think i have a problem about the rotation vector. how could we determine rotation vector? lets say, there is another coordinate system which is translated from the origin with the (X10,Y20,Z10)

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are asking. Are you trying to *determine* the rotation of one particle cloud with respect to another? Least-squares optimization problem?

Comment: I have an axis at (10,20,10) and i have points like p1(12,22,10), p2(14,24,14), p3(20,20,20). I want to rotate these points around that axis's z by theta.

Comment: What do you mean by "that axis' z"? If you simply want a transformation matrix for an arbitrary axis and angle, the link in my first comment ([this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19297/how-can-i-rotate-about-an-arbitrary-point-in-3d-instead-of-the-origin)) should be all you need.